# dynamicly change herf link with user text input

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, href

I have this code that I can't seem to get to work right, I hope that I am posting this correctly, I would like to have the user text input replace the original href link for 10 minutes and be clickable for other visitors for that duration and then return to the original href. Repeatable over and over again every 10 minutes. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeURLOfAnchorWithID(anchor_id,new_href)
 {
 document.getElementById("anchor").href = new_href;
 }

function formOnSubmit(formElm)
 {
 changeURLOfAnchorWithID("anchor",formElm.new_url.value+"");
 return false;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="anchor" href="https://www.whatever.com/">    <!--Keeps new url active for 10 minutes after user leaves site and other visitors are able to click there submitted link instead, then resets to default setting after 10 minutes-->
<img border="0" src="https://www.whatever.com" width="468" height="60"></a>   

<form onsubmit="return formOnSubmit(this)">
<input type="text" name="new_url" value="" size="36" /><br /> <!--value added to the end of the static address in the anchor tag -->
<input type="submit" value="change href" />
</form>
```

OK so this is what I've come up with,  **PHP works good** and updates the information on a separate page, I would like to have the information that is entered in the text box replace the end of an HREF link on the PHP page and remain there for 10 minutes minimum until someone else updates the PHP with there input. I've decided that there's no need for the link to revert back to the original link after the 10 minutes are up.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="phptest.php">
<textarea name="Box" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST["Box"] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this change visible to all users. You can't do this by only using JavaScript. JavaScript is a client side scripting language. It runs on the client's machine.

To make this possible, you have to use any server side scripting language like PHP,ASP or JSP. On submission, the link must go to the server and it should be stored in the database. When a new user requests the page, the page should be generated according to the link stored at the database.
To change change the link automatically after 10 minutes, use cron jobs. I trust this helps.